# VBA insert if - Change cell fill based on date

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to do an insert if formula in VBA for the following;

In my column K I want three conditions:

- Date is Today or older (ie project is due today or earlier) = RED
- Date is Today + up to 7 days = Amber
- Date is Today less more than 7 days = Green

I was thinking of using something along the lines of:

```
Sub ChangeColor()
    lRow = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set MR = Range("K3:K" & lRow)
    For Each cell In MR
        If cell.Value = "TODAY" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        If cell.Value = "TODAY-7days" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 9
        If cell.Value = "Morethan7Days" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Next
End Sub
```

I've been trying but I'm not sure how to do it.

I think my way is correct yet I am not sure how to code the If date=-7days then and so on.

Can someone provide some guidance? :)

Comment: why not use conditional formatting - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47426368/untitled.JPG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA has a Date function that returns today's date.  Dates in VBA are the number of days since December 31, 1900 (usually and with a leap year bug), so you can subtract or add integers to Date to get past and future days.

```
Sub ChangeColor()

    Dim rCell As Range

    With Sheet1
        For Each rCell In .Range("K3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp)).Cells
            If rCell.Value <= Date Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            ElseIf rCell.Value <= Date + 7 Then
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Else
                rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Next rCell
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Anderson is correct that you could accomplish this with conditional formatting however if you want to do this in VBA  Create a variable to hold the date and set it to the current day minus the time.  Then you just want to Format the cells value to a date format.  Once this is done you can use dateAdd to and and subtract the days.  See below

```
Sub ChangeColor()

Dim myDate As Date
'format the date excluding time
myDate = FormatDateTime(Now, 2)

lRow = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("K3:K" & lRow)
    For Each cell In MR
        If FormatDateTime(cell.Value, 2) = myDate Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        If FormatDateTime(cell.Value, 2) = DateAdd("d", -7, myDate) Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 9
        If FormatDateTime(cell.Value, 2) = DateAdd("d", 7, myDate) Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
    Next

End Sub
```

I did notice that your checking to see if it is equal so only dates that are exactly Todays date, 7 days from today and 7 days previous to today will have the interior color filled.   greater than and less than to fill all interior cell colors

Sorry for all the edits